# How to properly POST JSON array to avoid HTTP 400 Bad Request?

Tags: c#, json, dotnet-httpclient

I have a small C# app, which uses HttpClient to POST a JSON array to a REST API implemented in Java Jersey 2.0.

My client code looks like this:

```
public class Customer {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Address { get; set; }
}

Client.Customer customer1 = new Client.Customer {
  Name = "name 1", Address = "address 1"
};
Client.Customer customer2 = new Client.Customer {
  Name = "name 2", Address = "address 2"
};

List < Client.Customer > customerList = new List < Client.Customer > ();
customerList.Add(customer1);
customerList.Add(customer2);

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customerList);

EnvokeCreateCustomer("http://10.3.3.5:8080/", "jersey_test/webapi/customer", json).Wait();

static async Task EnvokeReadCustomer(string baseUrl, string apiUrl) {
  RestClient.Client restClient = new RestClient.Client();
  await restClient.ReadCustomer(baseUrl, apiUrl);
}

public async Task CreateCustomer(string baseUrl, string apiUrl, string customer) {
  using(var client = new HttpClient()) {
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");

    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(apiUrl, customer);
    var p = response;
  }
}
```

When I run this, I get HTTP 400 Bad Request.

When I use a small Python HttpClient code against the same API, it runs fine:

```
import json
import urllib2

data = [{"name":"Customer 1", "address":"customer address 1"},
        {"name":"Customer 2", "address":"customer address 2"}]
payload = json.dumps(data)

req = urllib2.Request('http://10.3.3.5:8080/jersey_test/webapi/customer')
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')

response = urllib2.urlopen(req, json.dumps(data))
```

What should I change in my C# code to make this POST work?

Comment: Try running both while having Fiddler running and you'll be able to see the  format differences. Then you'll know what changes you need to make.

Comment: Don't serialize `Customer`, it will happen automagically with `PostAsJsonAsync`.

Comment: Right, you're serializing `Customer` twice, which ends up with an escaped JSON.

Comment: Both SledgeHammer and Yuval were correct: using fiddler revealed that the API did not like upped cased Name (no idea why), which is what Yuval assumed to be the actual issue.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use Inspect Element in FireFox to see the header of a request in Network section. You should add some other headers. I think  the bellow ones will do the job:

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1");
```